# js comparation with or operator on left side

Tags: javascript, operators, comparator

I´m trying to make my comparation more concise this way, but it doesnt work:

```
if (this.filterControl.value === ("YES" || "NO"))
```

This one works:

```
if (this.filterControl.value === "YES" || this.filterControl.value === "NO")
```

Comment: `"YES" || "NO"` is always `"YES"`, because `"YES"` is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value. What you could try with multiple values is [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Like `['YES', 'NO'].includes(this.filterControl.value)`.

Comment: *"but it doesnt work"* - It "works" in the sense that it successfully performs the logic it's designed to perform.  That logic just isn't what you thought it would be.  *"This one works"* - It sounds like you've solved the problem then.  However, if what you're **implying** (but not asking) is how to test a value against a list of values, the linked duplicate can help with that.

Comment: Weird idea, you're not trying to make a comparison more concise, you're trying to make it more ambiguous... ;)